# Exception handling (contradicting documentation / try-finally vs. using)

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, using, unhandled-exception

I thought I had understood how exception handling in C# works. Re-reading the documentation for fun and self-confidence, I have run into problems:

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) claims that the following two code snippets are equivalent, even more, that the first one is translated to the latter one at compile time.

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) {
  byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

and

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Furthermore, it claims:

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
> exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

In contrast, [that document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) states:

> Within a handled exception, the associated `finally` block is guaranteed
> to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the
> `finally` block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is
> triggered.

I do not get this together. In the code example from the first document, the exception clearly is unhandled (since there is no catch block). Now, if the statement from the second document is true, the `finally` block is *not* guaranteed to execute. This ultimately contradicts what the first document says ("The `using` statement *ensures* ...") (emphasis mine).

So what is the truth?

**EDIT 1**

I still don't get it. StevieB's answer has made me read more parts from the C# language specification. In section 16.3, we have:

> [...] This search continues until a catch clause is found that can
> handle the current exception [...] Once a matching catch clause is
> found, the system prepares to transfer control to the first statement
> of the catch clause. Before execution of the catch clause begins, the
> system first executes, in order, any finally clauses that were
> associated with try statements more nested that than the one that
> caught the exception.

So have I made a simple test program which contains code which produces a division by zero and is within a `try` block. That exception is never caught in any of my code, but the respective `try` statement has a `finally` block:

```
int b = 0;

try {
  int a = 10 / b;
}
finally {
  MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

Initially, according to the documentation snippet above, I had expected that the `finally` block never would be executed and that the program just would die when being executed without a debugger attached. But this is not the case; instead, the "exception dialog box" we all know too well is shown, and after that, the "Hello" dialog box appears.

After thinking a while about that and after having read docs, articles and questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113755/c-sharp-exceptions-only-caught-when-debugging) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936947/exception-handling-problem-in-release-mode), it became clear that this "exception dialog box" is produced by a standard exception handler which is built into Application.Run() and the other usual methods which could "start" your program, so I am not wondering any more *why* the `finally` block is run.

But I am still totally baffled because the "Hello" dialog appears *after* the "exception dialog box". The documentation snippet above is pretty clear (well, probably I am just too silly again):

The CLR won't find a `catch` clause which is associated with the `try` statement where the division by zero happens. So it should pass the exception up one level to the caller, won't find a matching `catch` clause there as well (there is not even a `try` statement there) and so on (as noted above, I do not handle (i.e. catch) any exception in this test program).

Finally, the exception should meet the CLR's default catch-all exception handler (i.e. that one which is by default active in Application.Run() and its friends), but (according to the documentation above) the CLR should now execute all `finally` blocks which are more deeply nested than that default handler ("my" `finally` block belongs to these, doesn't it?) *before* executing the CLR catch-all default handler's `catch` block.

That means that the "Hello" dialog should appear *before* the "exception dialog box", doesn't it?. Well, obviously, it's the other way around. Could somebody elaborate on that?

Comment: It's a tiny bit unclear what you're asking. Are you basically asking whether a `using` will dispose 100% of the time? Because if so, you're right, no it will not (necessarily) since it is subject to the kind of exception that has been raised during the code it 'contains', similarly to the `try catch` you're maybe more familiar with.

Comment: I believe that by "unhandled", they mean the exception is unhandled by the application i.e. the exception is going to cause the application to end/crash.
Since the application is terminating, executing the finally block isn't necessarily required.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: i guess he's asking if it's possible that a `finally` doesn't execute on unhandled exceptions or what _exception unwind operation_ means. The link [Unhandled Exception Processing in the CLR](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=128371) in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) is rot

Comment: "... the exception clearly is unhandled..." - only in *that* block of code. There can be `catch` blocks higher up the call stack.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I am asking which of the documents is right. Obviously, one of them must be wrong, unless I have already lost even the rest of logical thinking that was in me ...

Answer (score 5):

> This document claims that the following two code snippets are equivalent

They are.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Pretty much.

> This ultimately contradicts what the first document says

Well, the first one was being a bit too vague, rather than flat-out incorrect.

There are cases where a `finally` will not run, including that implied by a `using`. A `StackOverflowException` would be one example (a real one from overflowing the stack, if you just do `throw new StackOverflowException()` the finally will run).

All the examples are things you can't catch, and your application is going down, so if the clean up from `using` is only important while the application is running, then `finally` is fine.

If the clean-up is vital even when the program crashes, then `finally` can never be enough, as it can't deal with e.g. a power plug being pulled out, which in the sort of cases where clean up is vital even in a crash, is a case that needs to be considered.

In any case where the exception is caught further up and the program continues, the `finally` will run.

With catchable exceptions that aren't caught, then `finally` blocks will generally run, but there are still some exceptions. One would be if the `try`-`finally` was inside a finaliser and the `try` took a long time; after a while on the finaliser queue the application will just fail-fast.

Comment: *"Well, the first one was being a bit too vague, rather than flat-out incorrect."* -- What exactly is vague in the statement *"The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object."*? Do you consider the word "ensure" to be vague? It is as clear as it can be (and flat-out incorrect). If this sentence is vague, then everything is vague, and we can't be sure about anything we read in Microsoft's docs.

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of "unhandled exception" (that it must be handled by a `catch` clause within the *same* `try` block) was correct, there would be no reason to ever allow the construct

```
try {
   ...
}
finally {
   ...
}
```

Since by your definition, the `finally` block would never run. Since the above construct is valid, we must conclude that your definition of "unhandled exception" is incorrect.

What it means is "if the exception is not handled by *any* exception handler, anywhere in the call stack".

Comment: You are right, in this context I understood it like: An unhandled exception is an exception which is not caught by the `catch` block *which belongs to the respective `try` block*. Obviously, I misinterpreted the term "unhandled" (I was well aware that I could catch exceptions in all callers up the stack, but did not assume that this was important in that context).

Answer (score 0):

The C# language specification states that the finally blocks will be executed (be that in a using statement or elsewhere) for System.Exception or any of its derived exceptions. Of course, if you get an exception that can't be handled with the usual try..catch logic e.g. AccessViolationException all bets are off which is where the ambiguity comes in.

The spec is installed with Visual Studio 2013 and later - with 2017 it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC#\Specifications\1033`

In section

> 8.9.5 The throw statement

we see the following:

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred
> to the first catch clause in an enclosing try statement that can
> handle the exception. The process that takes place from the point of
> the exception being thrown to the point of transferring control to a
> suitable exception handler is known as exception propagation.
> Propagation of an exception consists of repeatedly evaluating the
> following steps until a catch clause that matches the exception is
> found. In this description, the throw point is initially the location
> at which the exception is thrown.
>
> - In the current function member,
>   each try statement that encloses the throw point is examined. For each
>   statement S, starting with the innermost try statement and ending with
>   the outermost try statement, the following steps are evaluated:
>
>   - If
>     the try block of S encloses the throw point and if S has one or more
>     catch clauses, the catch clauses are examined in order of appearance
>     to locate a suitable handler for the exception. The first catch clause
>     that specifies the exception type or a base type of the exception type
>     is considered a match. A general catch clause (§8.10) is considered a
>     match for any exception type. If a matching catch clause is located,
>     the exception propagation is completed by transferring control to the
>     block of that catch clause.
>   - **Otherwise, if the try block or a catch
>     block of S encloses the throw point and if S has a finally block,
>     control is transferred to the finally block. If the finally block
>     throws another exception, processing of the current exception is
>     terminated. Otherwise, when control reaches the end point of the
>     finally block, processing of the current exception is continued**.
> - If
>   an exception handler was not located in the current function
>   invocation, the function invocation is terminated, and one of the
>   following occurs:
>
>   - If the current function is non-async, the steps
>     above are repeated for the caller of the function with a throw point
>     corresponding to the statement from which the function member was
>     invoked.
>   - If the current function is async and task-returning, the
>     exception is recorded in the return task, which is put into a faulted
>     or cancelled state as described in §10.14.1.
>   - If the current function
>     is async and void-returning, the synchronization context of the
>     current thread is notified as described in §10.14.2.
> - **If the
>   exception processing terminates all function member invocations in the
>   current thread, indicating that the thread has no handler for the
>   exception, then the thread is itself terminated. The impact of such
>   termination is implementation-defined**.

Comment: That's a big wall of quoted text to throw in - perhaps if you **emphasised** the key pieces of text that you think are most pertinent here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the documentation a little leeway.  In most circumstances there's an implied "within reason".  For example, if I turn my computer off none of those finally blocks or using/Disposes will be called.

Apart from the computer shutting off, there are a handful of circumstances that OS can terminate your application--effectively shutting it off.  In these circumstances `Dispose` and `finally` won't be invoked.  Those are usually pretty serious error conditions like *out of stack* or *out of memory*.  There are some complex scenarios where that can happen with less-than-exceptional-exceptions.  For example, if you have native code that creates a managed object on a background thread and that managed object and something on that thread throws an native exception, it's likely that the managed exception handlers won't get called (e.g. `Dispose`) because the OS will just terminate the thread and anything that could have been disposed is not accessible any more.

But, yes, those statements are effectively equivalent and within reason the `finally` block will be executed and `Dispose` will be called.

Answer (score -1):

I believe (correct me if I am wrong) the answer is lying in the definition:

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs **while you are calling methods on the object**.

So if any exceptions occur in any methods called by the object  of using, finally is ensured to run. On the other hand finally is not guaranteed to run  if inside the using block call other methods not related with the object cause an exception

Comment: Thanks for bringing that definition to our attention, but I think that the answer is not lying there. According to the other answers and what I had read before, it depends if the exception is handled (caught) in *any of the callers* up the stack.

Comment: The C# *Specification* doesn't contain any wording like this. I suspect this is another example of the authors of the C# *Reference* trying to add more explanation to a point and instead creating confusion.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, I would like to bring to your notice that **using** statement cannot be used for all types. This can be used only for types that implement **IDisposable** interface which has a functionality to dispose the object automatically. This is present in the second document you mentioned

> C# also contains the using statement, which provides similar functionality for IDisposable objects in a convenient syntax.

This means if an unhandled exception happens, cleaning up of your objects is handled by the Dispose() method of the type(this is given for using statement documentation)

Coming to the query, even though your finally block(generated) is not guarenteed to run for unhandled exceptions, the object dispose operation is handled during runtime by .Net CLR

Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: I cant see how this answers the Question

Comment: Interesting aspect, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: I'd like to know what part of the OP's question is using `using` incorrectly