# .Net Framework: Finally block is not being called when the exception is not being caught

Tags: c#, try-catch, console-application, unhandled-exception, finally

A simple console application, in Visual Studio 2019, .Net Framework 4.7, Windows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
         Console.WriteLine("In try");
         throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    finally
    {        *// Surprisingly this part is not being executed.*
         Console.WriteLine("In finally");
         Console.ReadLine();
    }                       
}
```

I was sure that finally block is being called in case of NO Exception, and in case of YES Exception.
I've read in the docs:

> However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block
> is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That,
> in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

Well, I'm confused. Do I need to do something with this "unwind operation" in order finally will be called in case of unhandled exceptions?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250582/exception-handling-contradicting-documentation-try-finally-vs-using) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Unwinding)

Comment: This answer from Eric Lipper should clarify it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196863/5311735

Comment: What I see after running this code: 1. In try 2. Unhandled Exception: ... 3. In finally | So what's the problem?

Comment: @SᴇM you should read the question again, i also popped it in dotnetfiddle and thought 'well this just works' but thats not what is asked here.

Comment: @sem Did you run it in a Console application? Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @SItzik Yes, I did.

Comment: May also depend on Platform. Is this .NET Framework or Core? What OS? (Framework, just realized, you stated it in question, sorry.)

Comment: @Evk and dontbyteme thank you for your comments, but as you can see in your links, the replies were not accepted as answers, and they don't help me neither. Eric explain the logic behind not to run the finally, so what should we do in order to run the finally block in case of an Unhandled exception?

Comment: @sommmen I'm not sure about other parts of the question, but the title is pretty clear to me. Maybe OP needs to edit the question/title, to less confuse readers.

Comment: _"what should we do in order to run the finally block in case of an Unhandled exception?"_ Do you actually want to force-run the finally block, or do you want to "run _something_ in case of unhandled exception" ? ( See [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-5.0))

Comment: Eric says that you cannot rely on finally block being run on unhandled exception. In some cases it might run, in others not, so that's what you should do - not rely on it being run

Comment: @Fildor Good point. I added these details to the question, and about what is the goal: The goal is that finally block will run no matter if there was an exception or not (handled or unhandled)

Comment: Since the finally block may not run on unhandled exception, but (and i'm going off on the internet here) will go on when the exception is handled, why don't you just add an empty `catch` statement that catches all exceptions?

Comment: I am not sure about the effect of it, but I'd try to register a handler for the UnhandledException event and see if that changes the treatment of the finally block.

Comment: To the people that use dotnetfiddle to check. try changin the compiler version from .net 4.7.2 to .net core 5 and observe that in the latter the finally block is indeed not being run as op claims

Comment: `The goal is that finally block will run no matter if there was an exception or not (handled or unhandled)` You can't, by definition. It it was possible then it would be guaranteed. But it isn't guaranteed. _OK, theoretically it could work even if it wasn't guaranteed - but even if it did, you couldn't **rely** on it working in the future._

Comment: `so what should we do in order to run the finally block in case of an Unhandled exception?` Catch it - to improve the odds that it isn't unhandled.

Comment: My point was, that it works just fine on my machine, but may not work on a different one, with different configs. And as many people stated here, the unhandled exception is a different situation, when the system can decide to terminate your process. You cannot expect `finally` block to work if you for example unplug/power off your machine while the `try` code is running.

Comment: @mjwills yes, to add catches will do the job, but it seems it contradicts what I thought Finally is. Now I see that in some machines it work, in some machines it doesn't... Scary. Lets take for example the using clause. It creates behind the scenes try and finally without catch, in order to promise dispose...now by our discussion, even this is not promised...

Comment: _"now by our discussion, even this is not promised..."_ only in case of an (completely) unhandled exception, though.

Comment: @SItzik You probably need to think this way - if your program runs "normally", in that case, `finally` will always be executed.

Comment: @Fildor, yes by the word "promised", I meant "any way" Unhandled exceptions or handled. The problem is that in some machines it will work and in some machines it will not work. So non accurate issue .

Comment: `even this is not promised...` Correct.

Comment: `@Fildor, yes by the word "promised", I meant "any way" Unhandled exceptions or handled.` By definition you know that can't really work, not 100% - e.g. for stack overflow. Thus you are dealing with degrees of confidence, not absolutes.

Comment: And I didn't even understand what configs I need to change in my machine in order the finally block will be called in such a case, like it was called to some of the users over here.

Comment: `And I didn't even understand what configs I need to change in my machine in order the finally block will be called in such a case,` Who said it was config related (I can't see that in the docs)? **If you want it more likely to be executed - add a `catch`**.

Comment: @ mjwills Right, and for cases of I turn off the electricity, but I thought that at least in simple cases, Finally will be done any how, if the code leave the try block, and this is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: Well, you cannot "promise" to execute _any_ code, really. That's the nature of unhandled (=unexpected) events. If lightning strikes your machine, no whatever sophisticated mechanism is going to guarantee execution of any code... But I get what you thought should be possible to achieve ...

Comment: `but I thought that at least in simple cases` And it does, in simple cases. The top of the call stack (e.g. Main) - debatable whether it is simple in that case.

Comment: @mjwills, I will add catches, but what about the "using clause"? it doesn't use catch. Only try and finally. By our conclusion, I would except that behind the scenes, it will use a catch, for to be sure the object will be disposed. Isn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't use `catch` (and it isn't documented to use it). You could test this to validate it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/KIabGl

Comment: @mjwills This is exactly what I say. The using clause doesn't use catch. Only try and Finally. So how can we be sure the Dispose() is going to be called?

Comment: @SItzik `So how can we be sure the Dispose() is going to be called?` You can't. As I said earlier.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111597/conditions-when-finally-does-not-execute-in-a-net-try-finally-block   so not true by our discussion.

Comment: Is it fair to say that an answer written 12 years ago may not have considered the implications of running on a different runtime and / or a different OS? Yes, that would be fair to say.

Comment: So actually there is not really a point in try and finally without using catches.

Comment: `there is not really a point` Sometimes seat belts don't help you survive a crash. And yet I wear one. Why? **Because usually they do**. There are limited situations where you need the catch. If this is a big deal for you **use the catch in those scenarios**.

Comment: Usually? if in such a simple case it doesn't help when it does? Do you have an example of another simple case when try and finally without catch, actually cause the finally block to be called?