# C# dispose - Is it all that I need?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a C# Windows application with ~20 Forms. Every form got its own variables and graphic elements(pen, rectangles, lines....). When user closes a form I am using

this.Dispose();

Is this all that I have to do for handling closing or I need to add something more?

Comment: `Is this all that I have to do for handling closing or I need to add something more?` Short answer - it depends. There _may_ be need for other `Dispose` calls as well - but calling `Dispose` / `Close` on the form is certainly a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Forms are shown with [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) have to be disposed (with `using` or calling `Dispose` manually). This is enough and you have not to do any more.

Forms are shown with [Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show) are disposed automatically (when [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close) method is executed) by .Net Framework, you should not dispose it manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var frm = new Form1())
   frm.ShowDialog();
```

Do NOT just call `Dispose()` outside of a `finally` block as this can fail when an exception is thrown

Comment: You are aware that `using` calls `Dispose` under the covers?

Comment: Yes, but calling `Dispose` outside a `finally` is just a no-no

Comment: To be fair, that (it not executing) is also possible even in a `finally` (if an exception is thrown) - but yes, `using` / finally block is the best we have, yes. Thanks for updating your answer - it is clearer now.

Comment: @mjwills no that is not possible. A `finally` will always execute unless there is a catastrophic exception (AccessViolation etc, or someone pulling the electric)

Comment: On Windows, sure. :) On Linux, not so much. https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsHFIf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069918/net-framework-finally-block-is-not-being-called-when-the-exception-is-not-bein#comment115038679_65069918

Comment: @mjwills What the h*ll? Is that Mono? Is that not a compiler bug? Just saw your link, wow

Comment: Nope, .NET Core on Linux. It isn't a bug. Its documented. :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally

Answer (score -1):

For opening new form; (this code not for Main form)

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.ShowDialog();
frm.Dispose();
```

For closing opened form;

```
this.Close();
```

Comment: You need a `using` or a`finally` block