# VB Application - Unhandle Exception not working in Release mode

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, logging, unhandled-exception

VB winforms Application, I have added this code in the ApplicationEvents so that I can catch all the unhandled exceptions and log them.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As Application.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
     AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf Application_UnhandledException
End Sub

Private Sub Application_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)     
    'My code for log
End Sub
```

This works perfectly in debug mode, but when it comes to Release this function is never called and I didn't understand why

I tried to see if their is a problem in the application config file

Comment: You need to move your `AddHandler` statement to `Program.Main` instead of `Application_Startup`.

Comment: Could be this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936947/exception-handling-problem-in-release-mode?rq=2

Comment: I tried that solution but when I added that statement at the top of my Main method a System.InvalidOperationException is throwed at the launching of the Application and it crashes.
The error is: Impossible to modify the mode of exception of the thread once controls have been created on that thread

Comment: The top of your *`Main` method*? Since you have Application Framework enabled, because you're handling the `Startup` event, what does *`Main` method* mean here? If you need Application Framework, then use the event it provides. Or disable it and do the *manual work*

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `Startup` handler with a `Handles` clause and then use `AddHandler` in that to register the `UnhandledException` event handler. Delete all the code you posted. Use the navigation bar at the top of the code window to generate the event handler with a `Handles` clause. Select the object whose event you want to handle in the middle drop-down, then select the even in the righthand drop-down.

Comment: There should be no talk of `Main` methods here. This is VB, not C#.

Comment: @Dai, that is simply wrong. With the application framework enabled, VB hides the `Main` method and manages it itself. It raises the `Startup` event and that is specifically where you're supposed to add code that you want executed at startup. Your advice might be considered valid for C# except there's no `Startup` event there to begin with, because there's no application frmaework.

Comment: @jmcilhinney "_This is VB, not C#_" - VB supports manually-defined, hand-written `Main` methods just fine - it's only when _Application Framework_ is enabled when the `Main` method is auto-generated. w.r.t. the OP's code, I wasn't sure if their `Application_Startup` event corresponded to either `My.Application` (`WindowsFormsApplicationBase`'s) `Startup` _or_ WinForms's `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Startup` event.

Comment: @Dai, there is no `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Startup` event. There's a `System.Windows.Application.Startup` event but that is for WPF, not WinForms. Yes, you can write your own `Main` method, but that seems unlikely in this case, given the givens.